# How to add background image to a listpicker?

Tags: windows-phone-8, listpicker

In my WP8 app I want to add an image to listpicker Backgrond.

How can I add it?

```
<toolkit:ListPicker  ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" Header="blabla:" Name="mylistpicker" Margin="0,395,222,47">

</toolkit:ListPicker>

<toolkit:ListPickerPage>
        <toolkit:ListPickerPage.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="=/images/bg3.png"/>
        </toolkit:ListPickerPage.Background>
</toolkit:ListPickerPage>
```

It did not work for me.
any other code please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an Image in Background of ListPicker, You can add ListPicker within a Grid and set Grid Background property to your desired Image.

```
<Grid Background="/path/a.jpg">
    //add ListPicker Here
</Grid>
```